# How to mock an injected bean in Mockito?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, mockito, ejb

This test works:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test1 {

    @InjectMocks private MyBean bean;       

    @Test
    public void shouldWork() {      
        bean.test("ABC");       
    }
}

@Stateless
public class MyBean {

    public String test(String s) {
        System.out.println("This is a test " + s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to inject a new EJB MyBean2 in MyBean and retest. To do that, I mock MyBean2 in Test1 as well. This is the new test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test1 {

    @Mock MyBean2 bean2;        
    @InjectMocks MyBean bean;       

    @Test
    public void shouldWork() {
         bean.test("ABC");      
    }

}


@Stateless
public class MyBean {

    @Inject
    MyBean2 bean2;

    public String test(String s) {
        return s + bean2.test2();
    }
}


@Stateless
public class MyBean2 {
    public String test2() {
        return "DEF";
    }
}
```

But when I run this I get `NullPointerException` when bean tries to invoke the bean2 method, probably because Mockito is not recognizing the injected bean as EJB.

How to make this work?

Comment: Why do you think `@InjectMocks` creates mocks? Just search for a simple mockito tutorial, it will explain how it should be used. Or just read the Javadoc of `InjectMocks` it explains that as well.

Comment: I couldn't find this information in the Mockito tutorial, can you point me to the link where it explains how to mock injected EJBs?

Comment: For example: https://www.journaldev.com/21887/mockito-injectmocks-mocks-dependency-injection#injectmocks-constructor-injection-example

Comment: The only thing different in this article is that `@InjectMocks MyBean2 bean2;` had to be replaced with `@Mock MyBean2 bean2;` but I'm still getting the NPE :)

Comment: Well, obviously. You _still_ try to mock `MyBean`, although the class expects `MyBean2`. What other result do you expect here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into the [Javadoc of `@InjectMocks`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html). It states that you have to call an init of the mocks in use by calling in your case:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test1 {
    @InjectMocks
    MyBean bean;
    @Mock
    MyBean2 bean2;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldWork() {
        when(bean2.test2()).thenReturn("mocked return");
        assertThat(bean.test("ABC")).isEqualTo("ABCmocked return");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting `NullPointerException` as bean2 is null in MyBean.

Comment: Yes my first answer only related to to init of the `@Mock` objects. I've now updated it, showing you also that it is of course still necessary to mock your method call of `bean2`.